# How is a systemd service unit activated by a timer unit?

Tags: systemd

Given a unit file foo.service

```
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.service
[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/bin/foo --prod
```

And a unit file foo.timer

```
# /etc/systemd/system/foo.timer
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 12:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

- What happens at 12:00 every day if foo.service is off? (it will probably be started)
- What happens at 12:00 every day if foo.service is already on? (will it be restarted?)

From reading man systemd.timer

> For each timer file, a matching unit file must exist, describing the
>   unit to activate when the timer elapses. By default, a service by the
>   same name as the timer (except for the suffix) is **activated**. Example: a
>   timer file foo.timer activates a matching service foo.service. The unit
>   to activate may be controlled by Unit= (see below).

- What does it mean to **activate** foo.service? Does it mean restart or verify that it's already started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the `systemd` service of a timer is a `oneshot` or `simple` (default) start-up type, which means the service runs a command and exits afterwards.
During the execution of the command given with `ExecStart`, the unit has the state `active (running)` and on exit something like `inactive (dead)`.

When using timers you do not activate the service with `systemctl enable --now foo.service` but rather enable the corresponding timer unit `systemctl enbale --now foo.timer`.
What the timer does is more or less a `systemctl start foo.service` at the time given.

---

> - What happens at 12:00 every day if foo.service is off? (it will probably be started)

The `foo.service` will be started but is not enabled (auto-start at boot).

> - What happens at 12:00 every day if foo.service is already on? (will it be restarted?)

If the service is in an `active (running)` state nothing will happen. `systemd` won't try to start a service if that is already running.

> - What does it mean to activate foo.service? Does it mean restart or verify that it's already started?

To activate a service means to start it, e.g. `systemctl start foo.service`.